# How to display multiple selected Contact to base page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have one event page which Which has standard field "Name" which is lookup to Contact and Lead, for this "Name" field I have custom multi select Contact vf page.
This lookup page will return list of selected contacts in list.
For these two pages I have created one common control.
Now I need to display the selected contact in my base page which is event page.
My problem is I am not able to display selected contact in my base page.

My Base Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="myControllerExtension" id="thisPage">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
var element = document.getElementById('thisPage:myForm:j_id28:j_id34:Contact_mlktp').value; 
    function openLookup(baseURL, width, modified, searchParam){
            var originalbaseURL = baseURL;
            var originalwidth = width;
            var originalmodified = modified;
            var originalsearchParam = searchParam;
            var lookupType = baseURL.substr(baseURL.length-3, 3);
            if(modified == '1') baseURL = baseURL + searchParam;
            var isCustomLookup = false;
            //Following "003" is the lookup type for Contact object so change this as per your standard or custom object
            if(lookupType == "003"){
                var urlArr = baseURL.split("&");
                var txtId = '';
                if(urlArr.length > 2){
                    urlArr = urlArr[1].split('=');
                    txtId = urlArr[1];
                }
                //Following is the url of Custom Lookup page.
                baseURL = "apex/MultipleContact?txt=" + txtId;
                //Following is the id of apex:form control "myForm".
                baseURL = baseURL + "&frm=" +escapeUTF("{!$Component.myForm}");
                if(modified == '1'){
                    baseURL = baseURL + "&lksearch=" + searchParam;
                } 
                //Following is the Id of inputField that is the lookup to be customized as custom lookup
                if(txtId.indexOf('Contact') > -1){
                    isCustomLookup = true;
                }
            }

            if(isCustomLookup == true){
                openPopup(baseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=480,toolbar=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no",true);
            }
            else{
                if(modified == '1') originalbaseURL = originalbaseURL + originalsearchParam;
                openPopup(originalbaseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+originalwidth+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no",true);
            }
        }
</script>
<apex:pagemessages />
<apex:form id="myForm"> <apex:pageBlock title="Event" mode="edit" rendered="true">
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton value="Done" action="{!csave}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Calendar Details" columns="2">
<apex:inputField value="{!Event.WhoId}" onchange="checkField();" required="true" rendered="{!NOT(readonly)}" id="Contact"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My Lookup Page:

```
    <apex:page controller="myControllerExtension" showheader="false" sidebar="false" tabStyle="Contact">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
                <apex:outputPanel id="top" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Search" style="font-weight:Bold;padding-right:10px;" for="txtSearch"/>
                        <apex:inputText id="txtSearch" value="{!searchString}"/>
                            <span style="padding-left:5px">
                            <apex:commandButton id="btnGo" value="Go" action="{!Search}" rerender="multiselectPanel"></apex:commandButton></span>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
            <c:MultiselectContactPicklist leftLabel="Available Contacts"
                leftOption="{!allContacts}"
                rightLabel="Selected Contacts"
                rightOption="{!selectedContacts}"
                size="14"
                width="150px" />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:outputText >{!message}</apex:outputText>
```

Here goes my Controller:

```
public with sharing class myControllerExtension {
public String user_id {get; set;}
public Event ent {get;set;}
public boolean readonly  {get;set;}
public boolean showEdit {get;set;}
public List<Contact> results{get;set;}

private static final string DONE_TRUE = 'true';
private List<Id> lookupId = new List<Id>();

Id envId;
ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl;
    public PageReference csave() {
    try {
          upsert(ent);     
          readonly = true;
        }
    catch(System.DMLException e)
        {
          ApexPages.addMessages(e);       
        }
       pageReference pg= new pageReference ('/apex/mySecondPage?id='+ent.id+'&done=true');
       pg.setRedirect(true);
       return pg;
    }

    public PageReference Search() {
    system.debug('Inside search.... ');
    performSearch(searchString);
    return null;
}

private void performSearch(string searchString){
    String queryName = '%' + searchString + '%';
    system.debug('Search sTring.... '+searchString +' querynameess.s... '+queryName);
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    selectedContacts = new List<SelectOption>();   
    String soql = 'select id, name from Contact';
    system.debug('Contactssss using soql.... '+soql);
    if(searchString !='' && searchString != null)
        {
            soql = soql + ' where name like:queryName';
            soql = soql + ' limit 25';
            system.debug('Soql..... stringsss... '+soql);
        }
        contacts = Database.query(soql);
        system.debug('Contactssss in Listsss... '+contacts);
    allContacts = new List<SelectOption>();
    for ( Contact c : contacts ) {
        allContacts.add(new SelectOption(c.Id, c.Name));
    }
       system.debug('All contacts listssstt... '+allContacts);
}


    public PageReference save() {
    message = 'Selected Contacts: ';
    Boolean first = true;
    for ( SelectOption so : selectedContacts ) {
        if (!first) {
            message += ', ';
        }
        message += so.getLabel() + ' (' + so.getValue() + ')';
        first = false;
    }    
}


}
```

So basically on click of Save button in my Lookup page it should close the page and show the selected contact in my base page.

Comment: Please post your code which will help us to find where you are struggling and provide solutions accordingly.

Comment: Now I have posted my code.